# android can not access the local html

Tags: android, html, local

> I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Not allowed to load local resource:
>   file:///android_asset/webkit/android-weberror.png", source:
>   data:text/html,chromewebdata (0) I found many methods to solve
>   it,like:
>   webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/assets/wwww/js/mypage.html");

```
webView.loadUrl("file:///assets/mypage.html");

webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/mypage.html");
```

All of them can not work.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that your file mypage.html really exists inside `/assets` directory:

[image]

```
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/mypage.html");
```

---

you need to declare the permission into your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Using Android 6.0+ must request `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permissions manually:

```
private void checkExternalStoragePermission() {
    int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.i("Message", "PERMISSION NOT SET.");
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 225);
    } else {
        Log.i("Message", "Permission OK!");
    }
}
```